# Horizontal ScrollView Not Scrolling in React Native

Tags: react-native, scrollview, expo, styled-components, horizontalscrollview

I'm trying to render a horizontal scroll view of clickable photos.
The vertical scroll works fine, but once I set horizontal={true}, I'm limited to how far I can scroll horizontally. It prevents me from scrolling more than what is shown in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHknB.png).

```
<Container>
       <ScrollView
      horizontal={true}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: "5%"
      }}
    >
      {posts.map(post => {
        return (
          <TouchableOpacity
            key={post.id}
            style={{
              width: width,
              flex: 1,
              height: height / 3,
              borderRadius: "8px",
              overflow: "hidden",
              marginRight: "2%"
            }}
          >
            <Thumbnail
              source={{
                uri: uri`
              }}
            />
            <PostTitle>{post.name}</PostTitle>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        );
      })}
    </ScrollView>
</Container>
```

```
const Container = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  padding-top: 18%;
  background: #fff;
`;

const Title = styled.Text`
  color: #333;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding-left: 8%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
`;


const Thumbnail = styled.Image`
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  resize-mode: cover;
`;

const PostTitle = styled.Text`
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10%;
  left: 8%;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed. Removed "marginRight" and it worked. Horizontal ScrollView doesn't like styling its children's margins.

Answer (score 1):

The problem certainly is from the margin. However, I've found that specifically, ***setting the margin in percentage values*** or adding `flex: 1` to `contentContainerStyle` is what causes this problem.